# Updating the Yaml file, with new fields using ruamel

Tags: yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I am trying to update the yaml file using ruamel python.

```
proc=subprocess.Popen(['kubectl','get','pod','web3','-o','yaml','--export'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
rein=proc.stdout.read()
result, indent, block_seq_indent = ruamel.yaml.util.load_yaml_guess_indent(rein, preserve_quotes=True)
```

So far I have tried :

```
result['spec'].append('nodeSelector')
```

which gives ERROR :

```
result['spec'].append('nodeSelector')
AttributeError: 'CommentedMap' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Also tried like this :

```
result['spec']['nodeSelector']['kubernetes.io/hostname']='kubew1'
```

gives :

```
result['spec']['nodeSelector']['kubernetes.io/hostname']='kubew1'
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ruamel/yaml/comments.py", line 752, in __getitem__
return ordereddict.__getitem__(self, key)
KeyError: 'nodeSelector'
```

My Intial Yaml File is :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: demo
    name: web
  name: web3
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/web3
spec:
  containers:
  - image: aexlab/flask-sample-one
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: web
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5000
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-7bcc9
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
```

And Expected fields I want to add inside 'spec' is :

```
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/hostname: kubew1
```

Any Ideas how to achieve this with ruamel library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your YAML file your root level collection is a mapping and the value for the key `spec` in that mapping is itself a mapping. Both of those mappings get loaded as `dict`-like objects using `ruamel.yaml` named `CommentedMap`.

As with normal `dict`s you can add key-value pairs, deleted keys (and their values), and update values for a key, but there is no `.append()` method, as there is with a list (i.e. appending an extra item to a list).

Your output is a bit terse, but of course you cannot just add `nodeSelector` to anything (list/sequence nor dict/mapping) and expect that to add `kubernetes.io/hostname: kubew1` (a mapping in its own right) automatically.

Your try of:

```
result['spec']['nodeSelector']['kubernetes.io/hostname'] = 'kubew1'
```

cannot work because there is no dict `result['spec']['nodeSelector']` where you can add the key `kubernetes.io/hostname`.

You would either first have to create a key with an emtpy dict as value:

```
result['spec']['nodeSelector'] = {}
result['spec']['nodeSelector']['kubernetes.io/hostname'] = 'kubew1'
```

or do

```
result['spec']['nodeSelector'] = {'kubernetes.io/hostname': 'kubew1'}
```

Please note that the above has nothing much to do with `ruamel.yaml`, that is just basic Python data structure manipulation. Also note that there are over 100  libraries in the ruamel namespace, out of which `ruamel.yaml` is just one of several published as open source, so using `ruamel` is not very clear statement, although of course the context often provides enough information on which library you actually use.